# Realm.io, get NPE when trying to set list to a realm object

Tags: android, realm

I tried to add a list of Realm objects to another one, but hit NPE

```
        realm.beginTransaction();

        // Add a person
        Person person = realm.createObject(Person.class);
        person.setId(1);
        person.setName(name);

        RealmList<Cat> listOfCats = new RealmList<Cat>();
        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
            Cat cat = new Cat();
            if(i!=5)
                cat.setName("cat "+i);
            else
                cat.setName("Tung");
            listOfCats.add(cat);
        }
        person.setCats(listOfCats);

        // When the write transaction is committed, all changes a synced to disk.
        realm.commitTransaction();
```

the line `person.setCats` triggers this error:

```
       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'long io.realm.internal.Row.getIndex()' on a null object reference
```

If I change the code to do **inside** the `for` loop:

```
       person.getCats().add(cat)
```

instead of using the a separate realm list, it works, but I'm curious why the first way doesn't, since writing code in the second way seems cumbersome.
Thanks

Comment: Mixing managed and standalone objects is never a good idea. In general you don't want to have two copies of your data (one in memory and one in Realm), since Realm does a fair bit of effort to be a no-copy storage solution that will save you precious memory. This means that for maximum performance you should also instantiate cats with the static constructor to get a managed object to begin with.

Comment: @Emanuelez thanks, can you elaborate on the part `instantiate cats with the static constructor to get a managed object`?

Comment: Use `realm.createObject(Cat.class)` instead of `new Cat()` whenever you can. :)